# Wordpress: How get $_POST and $_GET?

Tags: wordpress

I want get user behavior in website

I use `print_r($_POST+$_GET)` but return empty array

```
Array()
```

Can you say to me best solution for this problem ?

Answer (score 0):

You could use `print_r( $_REQUEST );`.

This will output an array with the content of `$_POST`, `$_GET` and `$_COOKIE` as you can read in the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.request.php).

Answer (score 0):

For that you have to use **$_REQUEST**.

```
print_r($_REQUEST);
```

This will print both $_POST as well $_GET. 
Thanks